# How to find the norm using the equation of a circle?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Assume that we are given a normed vector space $(V,||.||)$ and an implicit equation as $f(v)=0$ of the unit circle on it. Now how to find the norm $||.||$.

My idea: What about constituting the equation $f(\frac{v}{||v||})=0$ and then finding $||v||$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $v$, you have to solve the equation $f(tv)=0$ for a positive number $t$. Then $\|v\| = 1/t$.

There is nothing more to say in such generality: how we solve $f(tv)=0$ depends entirely on what $f$ is.